# Trouble inserting JSON object into MySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, .htaccess

I am calling a Rest API in my PHP code which returns JSON. I want to save some parts of that into my database but for some reason, nothing is being stored. Here is what the JSON should look like:

```
{
"url": "http://myURL.com/fujifilm-mx1700.jpg",
"mimeType": "image/jpeg",
"width": 640,
"height": 480,
"byteSize": 100227,
"exif": {"YResolution": "72/1", "Tag0xa217": "2", "ResolutionUnit": "Inch", "Compression": "6", "Copyright": "", "Tag0xa300": "[ 3 ]", "Make": "FUJIFILM", "Flash": "no", "DateTime": "2000:09:02 14:30:10", "MaxApertureValue": "3.3", "YCbCrPositioning": "2", "XResolution": "72/1", "JPEGInterchangeFormatLength": "4354", "ExposureBiasValue": "0.0", "ExposureProgram": "Program Normal", "ShutterSpeedValue": "1/169", "ColorSpace": "1", "Tag0xa20e": "1087/1", "Tag0xa20f": "1087/1", "ExifImageWidth": "640", "DateTimeDigitized": "2000:09:02 14:30:10", "DateTimeOriginal": "2000:09:02 14:30:10", "BrightnessValue": "76/10", "CompressedBitsPerPixel": "2/1", "Interoperability_IFD_Pointer": "708", "FNumber": "7", "ApertureValue": "5.6", "Tag0xa210": "3", "FocalLength": "9.9", "Tag0xa000": "[ 48,49,48,48 ]", "ComponentsConfiguration": "[ 1,2,3,0 ]", "ExifImageHeight": "480", "ISOSpeedRatings": "125", "Model": "MX-1700ZOOM", "Software": "Digital Camera MX-1700ZOOM Ver1.00", "Orientation": "1", "Tag0xa301": "[ 1 ]", "JPEGInterchangeFormat": "856", "MeteringMode": "5", "ExifVersion": "[ 48,50,49,48 ]"}
}
```

And here is my PHP

```
$exif = file_get_contents('http://img2json.appspot.com/go/?url=http://myURL.com/$fileName');
$response = json_decode($response, true);

foreach($response['exif'] as $item) {

$iso = $item['ISOSpeedRatings'];
$shut = $item['ShutterSpeedValue'];

$sql="INSERT INTO EXIF (uniqueID, ISO, shutterSpeed)
VALUES('$id','$iso','$shut')";  

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$link)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

I want to store ISOSpeedRatings and ShutterSpeedValue in my database, but it they keep coming up empty.

I suspect its not working because I am not properly retrieving the data I want from the JSON, but I am not too sure what to do. Also, I think its worth noting that I am using AppFog so I had to make sure I had `php_value allow_url_fopen 1` in my .htaccess, since I have no access to the php.ini file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `var_dump($response);` to see if the response is proper and how it's setup

Comment: This code is never actually seen, but called from another page to store data periodically. Where would I look for the result of the var_dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP string interpolation (the thing that makes it replace variable names with their values in a string) only works (as far as I know) in a double-quoted string. If I'm reading it right, and my brain still works this late at night, your problem is here:

```
    $exif = file_get_contents('http://img2json.appspot.com/go/?url=http://myURL.com/$fileName');
```

Because you are literally requesting the file `'$filename`' rather than whatever is actually in that variable. Replace the single-quotes with double-quotes and see if that fixes it.

Update: next problem:

```
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
```

You need to decode the `$exif` variable.

Comment: I believe you are correct, so I fixed that. My table is still coming up empty though. I don't know why but I'm not very confident in the foreach loop I have (partially because there is only one instance of 'exif' that I'm looking for), and also the fact that I'm using `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Are there supposed to be multiple of the objects you listed returned in the response, or just one? Because with that response what you'll be doing is looping through each key value of an associative array containing only the exif data. Just take the loop out altogether and use `$response['exif']['ISOSpeedRatings']` etc..

Comment: Just one. Basically this file is called upon image upload to store the image, and to grab its exif data.

Comment: I might've edited my last comment after you read it (late at night, brain not working, forgot a sentence). Just get rid of your loop and work directly on the `$response['exif']` variable.

Comment: Trying that now. For some reason things broke and now my previous data that was being stored into a different table stopped working. I'll post back in a moment.

Comment: I am still not able to store the values of the JSON objects. I can't get ISOSpeedRatings to store, for instance, but I can get uniqueID and other things that I created to store just fine. The JSON object values simply remain blank in the database. Is it the `file_get_contents`? I read that I could use cURL, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: You need to do a `var_dump` to verify what's actually in the `$response` variable, and maybe also what url you're actually hitting (put it in a variable before you call `file_get_contents`, then just pass that variable in). If your page that you're dumping to is really big, do an `echo "dumping variable"` first, then Ctrl+f for "dumping variable" to find it.

Comment: Wait, I see another problem. Updating my answer.

Comment: See my edit. Pretty sure that's the main problem at this point, if you're no longer using a single-quoted url or an unnecessary loop.

Comment: It worked! Sometimes it takes a pair of fresh eyes (and all your expertise). You were super helpful. I fixed the quotes, the loop, and the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `urlencode()` to prepare your urlstring.

Comment: I did `$myUrl = urlencode('http://img2json.appspot.com/go/?url=http://myUrl.com/$fileName');
$exif = file_get_contents('$myUrl');` and I didn't notice a difference. The table is still empty.

Comment: try doing it like this: `$exif = file_get_contents($myUrl);`

Comment: No cigar. I'll use urlencode() but I think that perhaps the issue stems from something else.

Comment: Try it like this `$myUrl = urlencode('http://img2json.appspot.com/go/?url=http://myUrl.com/'.$fileName); $exif = file_get_contents($myUrl);`

Comment: Nothing unfortunately

Comment: you can try this in your foreach statement:  `echo $item['ISOSpeedRatings'];
echo $item['ShutterSpeedValue'];` Than you can see if there are some values.

Comment: The problem is that his code is never actually seen in action, but called from another page to store data periodically. If I echo something I won't be able to see it-- or is there a way I can?

Comment: You can try writing the values to a file. `$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "TestString\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = $item['ISOSpeedRatings'];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);`

Comment: That's not working for me. I'm on AppFog so I don't know if they are blocking something from happening on their end.

Comment: Ultimately I fixed the problem, but using urlencode() actually prevented it from working because of the way the API processes the URL I guess. But it was a great tip for the future. Thanks for all your help!